# Magento - Varnish / ESI:Include / Custom Pricing Based on Cookie

Tags: performance, magento, varnish, esi

I am implementing esi:includes in a site using Varnish. The main reason for doing this is to be able to serve users north / south pricing based on their postal code that gets saved to a cookie. However, the performance seems to be quite an issue now. See: http://stage.mobelringen.trollweb.no/soverommet/sovesofaer.html

Price blocks are loading individually, and slowly.

Is there a better way to implement this; for example, modifying the url to specify 'n' or 's' once the user's region is determined, so that product and category pages can be cached in their entirety in both 'n' and 's' versions?

Comment: You are supplying the answer yourself... By the way, currently everything is a 404 on the link supplied...

Comment: i dont see any esi tags, also varnish cache not working properly. some configuration issue.